# Fetch - respond to preflight response

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api, preflight

I am struggling with fetch over CORS, with authorization:

```
const token = 'this.is.secret!';
fetch('http://corsserver/api/hello', {
    method: 'get',
    credentials: 'include',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}).then(response => {
  console.log(response);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

When I run this request, Chrome sets the header as:

`Request Method:OPTIONS`

I look this up and [it's a preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS#Preflighted_requests_in_CORS).

I mean, that's really cool and stuff. However I can't figure out how to send the actual request after the preflight comes back okay! What's the next step? How do I send the GET request?

I'm missing something very basic here.

Comment: Incidental point: It seems unnecessary to be sending a `Content-Type` request header for a `GET` request… There’s no body in the `GET` to give a content-type to…

Comment: I’m guessing the OPTIONS might be failing due to the server requiring authentication for that OPTIONS request. See the update I tacked on to the answer just now

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Browsers will automatically send the actual `GET` request if the `OPTIONS` request is successful. But if the `OPTIONS` request isn’t successful, browsers will never make the `GET` request.

And there’s no way make that `GET` request without the browser doing the `OPTIONS` request.

So if the browser isn’t doing the `GET`, it can only mean the `OPTIONS` must be failing, and you need to find out why. The browser should be logging a message with the reason to its devtools console, so you should start by checking there (and then either edit/update the question to add that info, or post a new separate more-specific question with the error message).

---

One guess for what the problem could be: Maybe the server is requiring authentication for the `OPTIONS` request. If so, you need to fix it so that the server doesn’t—because when the browser makes the `OPTIONS` request, it doesn’t send the `Authorization` header+value from your code.

Instead in fact the whole purpose of the `OPTIONS` request in this case is for the browser to ask, *Are you OK with getting cross-origin requests that have an `Authorization` request header?*, and for the server to respond in way that indicates if it allows the `Authorization` header.

So because of that, the server must be configured to respond to any `OPTIONS` requests (from allowed origins at least) with a 2xx success response, without requiring authentication.

The way you’d know whether the server is requiring authentication for that OPTIONS request is if the CORS message your browser is logging shows a 401 status for the `OPTIONS` response.

---

Example code for handling the `OPTIONS` in a Node.js server environment:

```
if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
  res.send();
  return;
}
```

…to make the server send a 200 response with no response body, which is what you want for this. Do note that this explicitly allows all OPTION requests.